# Installer for Mac OSX did not provide option for changing path to version Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.5

Installer for Mac OSX did not provide option for changing path to version Python 3.5.2

How do I adjust the terminal path to this Python version 3.5.2?

Comment: Have you tried doing `py` or `python` or `python3` in the console? Maybe it's already in the path.

Comment: If you have both Python 2.7 and 3.5.2 installed, the `python` command starts Python 2, while `python3` starts Python 3, perhaps this is your issue?